# Tensorflow object detection API - Setting specific color to bounding boxes

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to detect 3 different classes of objects in images using Tensorflow Object Detection. I would like to set the bounding box color for each class to a custom color of my choice in order to suit my application.

For example,
Class 1: Red
Class 2: Blue
Class 3: Green

Unfortunately, Tensorflow object detection automatically sets this colors and I do not know how to change them.

I would be very gratefull for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by passing a `track_ids` to function [`visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3768f4cf13a6cc19cba88a96cf0efed384996a58/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L684).

Notice that when detection is performed, this plot function is called to visualize the bounding boxes on images.

Here is how to get the variable `track_ids`. First you should look at the [`STANDARD_COLORS`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3768f4cf13a6cc19cba88a96cf0efed384996a58/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L40) list and get the index of the color you want to draw boxes with. For example, 'Red' color's index is 98. Then you should loop through the variable `output_dict['detection_classes']` (this variable is also passed to the plot function), and when encounter class 1, `track_ids` is appended with 98. By doing this you will create a list of indexes of colors as `track_ids`, then transform this to a numpy array and pass it together into the plot function, then you should have all classes plotted as the color you assigned.

Comment: thank you for your awnser! it really worked. Also if you don't want the "ID: x" appearing in the bounding box text (I find it really ugly) you just need to pass the skip_track_ids as True in the function call.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use track_ids in the function?